# What is the difference between a public = $default and public = $test?

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm trying to learn something new by going through CakePHP's tutorials and in the section where you link a `database.php` to your MAMP/SQL, it asks for you to change the information in an array calls `public $default`. However there is also a `public $test` array in the same file.

What is the `public $test` array for? I know I can run my page by just linking the `$default` but does the `$test` serve a purpose?

ie:

```
class DATABASE_CONFIG {

    public $default = array(
        'datasource' => 'Database/Mysql',
        'persistent' => false,
        'host' => 'localhost',
        'login' => 'admin',
        'password' => 'admin',
        'database' => 'blog_tutorial',
        'prefix' => '',
        //'encoding' => 'utf8',
    );

    public $test = array(
        'datasource' => 'Database/Mysql',
        'persistent' => false,
        'host' => 'localhost',
        'login' => 'admin',
        'password' => 'admin',
        'database' => 'blog_tutorial',
        'prefix' => '',
        //'encoding' => 'utf8',
    );
}
```

Just curious, thanks!

Comment: Never used CakePHP before but isn't it just 2 different configurations that would allow you to run 2 different database according to your environment (production, development) ?

Comment: I thought one might be for testing purposes only, but if i use my `localhost:8888` it always links to the `public $default`.

I know little to no php, aside from creating a form that submits to itself, just don't want to not fill this out than be in trouble later on.

Comment: you are correct it's for testing purpose only.

Comment: $test is used for unit testing, $default is used almost always

Comment: Just for the sake of asking, how to view it with the `public $test` array then?  Is it a special url?

Comment: The test shell automatically initializes the test config settings when starting unit tests. Ideally it should be an empty database as it will create insert and drop data every time tests are run. In your model you can change the default database config by using `public $useDbConfig = 'someOtherConfigArray';`

Comment: Great, thanks for clearing this up @mcgowan.b!

Comment: Just try to spend 5 minutes with the documentation it is almost *everything* documented there: http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/database-basics.html#database-configuration Cakes documentation is excellent, you just have to use it.